# How to set virtual host for OTRS URL in rhel 6

Tags: rhel-6

i installed otrs successfully all are working fine but i have to set an simple name instead of OTRS URL in RED HAT 6 operating System. I'm new to RHEL and i dont know how to set the virtual host.

http://ipaddress/otrs/index.pl to simple name service.local

http://ipaddress/otrs/customer.pl to again simple name responce.local

in WAN (private area network). i required just like above please guys help me to set the virtual host.

Thanks advance,

Regards GK

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) is documentation for apache httpd how to make virtual hosts

Comment: Thanks for reply @RN, i want for Perl script. it accept only html format files. i googled it and gathered lot of answer(source code) for virtual host but it s not working till. check this http://forums.otterhub.org/viewtopic.php?f=60&t=9329

Comment: As far as I remember you can serve perl files in apache via mod_perl

Comment: mod_perl ? how to please give me steps to do it. @RN

Comment: Check here: http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_6&p=httpd&f=9

Comment: Thanks Romeo, i edited the perl.conf file but after restart the httpd it gives error.

Comment: this is my error log    Insecure dependency in require while running with -T switch at /opt/otrs//Kernel/Config/Defaults.pm line 35.\nBEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/otrs//Kernel/Config/Defaults.pm line 35.\nCompilation failed in require at (eval 8) line 3.\nBEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/otrs//Kernel/Config.pm line 224.\nCompilation failed in require at /opt/otrs/scripts/apache2-perl-startup.pl line 69.\nBEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/otrs/scripts/apache2-perl-startup.pl line 69.\nCompilation failed in require at (eval 2) line 1

Comment: @GopalKrishnan, this seems to be related to some features of your software. Please check them

Comment: Actually i'm setting alias name for OTRS URL, in private network the OTRS server is called with the help of ip address only, instead of that use local name to call the application may easy to remember the path. please help me @Romeo.

Comment: You can use apache as reverse proxy and provide hostname via apache virtual hosts. Is this you try to accomplish?

Comment: i'm new to linux, sorry what you are telling i cant understand.but if it solves the problem. i will be very happy.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to set up OTRS as a virtualhost - so you can enter as url only otrs.domain.com.

This is how I've done it:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName otrs.domain.com
  DocumentRoot "/opt/otrs/bin/cgi.bin/"
  DirectoryIndex index.pl
  Alias /otrs-web/ "opt/otrs/var/httpd/htdocs/"
  <Location "/otrs-web/">
    SetHandler default-handler
  </Location>
</Virtualhost>
```

In the apache otrs.conf you need to edit everything that has /otrs/xxxxx to /xxxxx

Logic behind it is - in normal apache configuration you need to say which folder is your cgi folder. Well, if you set up a root folder as your cgi folder, everything in that subfolder will be considered as script and you won't be able to get any other file. In this example: any .css, .png etc. That's why you need to tell apache that /otrs-web location is set as default-handler and not script-handler.

Works like a charm ;-)